# I need to achieve this using HTML, CSS and JavaScript - any help will be great

Tags: javascript, html, css, webforms

> Do you wish to include designation in the e-form?
>
>  Yes
>
>  No

If they select Yes, the following question will appear,

> Which you want to apply - (Check all that apply)
>
>  He/ HimHim
>
>  She /Her
>
>  TheyThey They/TheirTheir
>
>  Other (open(open (openfieldfield to typetype in )

Comment: You've tagged webforms.  Are you specifically wanting a webforms solution?

Answer (score 0):

This type of thing can be pretty easily achieved with jquery if that is an option for you, or even with plain javascript. A quick google search brought up this simple example that may help you: http://form.guide/html-form/html-checkbox-events.html You'll want to look at the sections on checkbox click events and on showing/hiding content on click.

Comment: Once I check the check box I another checkbox options should appear..

Which you want to apply - (Check all that apply) 
 He/ Him  
She /Her  
They/Their  
Other (open field to type in )